# Draw a THICK curve on a tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, drawing, tkinter-canvas

I want to use the tkinter Canvas object to draw handwriting on the screen. Using the [example code from the tkdocs website](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/canvas.html), I get the following drawing artifacts when I use a large line width of say 20:

[image]

However, for small line widths, everything's fine:

[image]

Here's the complete Python code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Sketchpad(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.save_posn)
        self.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.add_line)
        
    def save_posn(self, event):
        self.lastx, self.lasty = event.x, event.y

    def add_line(self, event):
        self.create_line((self.lastx, self.lasty, event.x, event.y))
        self.save_posn(event)

root = Tk()
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

sketch = Sketchpad(root)
sketch.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

root.mainloop()
```

I'm using Python 3.8.

What I tried so far:

- different joinstyles have no effect
- the smooth argument has no effect
- various unsuccessful dirty hacks and workarounds not worth to mention

Anybody an idea how I can get rid of the artifact?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try replacing `self.create_line` with `self.create_oval` and check if that produces your desired effect?

Comment: Yes, that almost worked! I replaced the `self.create_line` by two `self.create_oval` statements for the start and end of the "line". Works if I draw slowly, not if I draw quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `capstyle='round'` in `create_line()`:

```py
self.create_line((self.lastx, self.lasty, event.x, event.y), width=20, capstyle='round')
```

Comment: That did it! Still not sure why the standard capstyle is not working, but setting it to `ROUND` really solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new line for every `<B1-Motion>` event instead of extending one line towards every new point. Therefore, each new piece of the line doesn't know about the previous pieces and no effort is made to nicely connect all points. You don't notice this as much with thinner lines, but if you take a close look you can actually see it in the bends of the thin line you showed as well.

You can use a round capstyle to make the problem invisible because the caps fill all space between the lines, but to me it would make more sense to just create one line line and update its coordinates by creating a line on `<Button-1>` and extending it on `<B1-Motion>`:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class Sketchpad(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.new_line)
        self.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.add_to_line)

    def new_line(self, event):
        self.points = [event.x, event.y]
        self.line = self.create_line(event.x, event.y, event.x, event.y, width=20, capstyle=ROUND)

    def add_to_line(self, event):
        self.points.extend([event.x, event.y])
        self.coords(self.line, *self.points)


root = Tk()
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

sketch = Sketchpad(root)
sketch.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

root.mainloop()
```

Note that is still might look better to use a round [`capstyle`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/cap-join-styles.html), but now it only affects the ends of the line, as it's supposed to.