# How to draw on an image Tkinter canvas, PIL

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

I would want to be able to draw on an image being displayed by a tkinter canvas PIL. I tried google searching but all the results would be how to draw on an image without tkinter or how to display an image which is not what i want. I also would like it to be like live(color while i move my mouse). Is there any way to do this. If there are no ways with PIL is there a way with tkinter.

**Answer**

the answer from this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69001376/draw-a-thick-curve-on-a-tkinter-canvas)
if the link wont work here is the code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Sketchpad(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.save_posn)
        self.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.add_line)
        
    def save_posn(self, event):
        self.lastx, self.lasty = event.x, event.y

    def add_line(self, event):
        self.create_line((self.lastx, self.lasty, event.x, event.y), width=20, capstyle='round')
        self.save_posn(event)

root = Tk()
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

sketch = Sketchpad(root)
sketch.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can use Pillow [`ImageDraw`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html) module.

Comment: Yes i have done my research on that but i dont know how to use that with tkinter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to do the drawing with `tkinter` because otherwise you will need to continually update the canvas widget every time the image gets changed by the PIL (which might be too slow and interfere with "live" drawing).

`tkinter` `Canvas`es have several different vector and text drawing capabilities, and you can draw/display them *on top* of an image that's also being displayed by it. This means if you first add an image, anything further that is drawn will appear on top of that (if it overlaps the image).

Below is a demonstration of doing that. Note I borrowed some of the code and the sample image from the [python-course.eu](https://python-course.eu/tkinter) page: [Canvas Widgets in Tkinter](https://python-course.eu/tkinter/canvas-widgets-in-tkinter.php). It describes the drawing facilities supplied by `Canvas` widgets.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import *

canvas_width, canvas_height = 300, 300

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
canvas.pack()

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='rocks.png')
canvas.create_image(20, 20, anchor=NW, image=img)

# Draw something on top of image.
points = [100, 140, 110, 110, 140, 100, 110, 90, 100, 60, 90, 90, 60, 100, 90, 110]
canvas.create_polygon(points, outline='green', fill='yellow', width=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Here's the [`rocks.png`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggvxJ.png) image the code uses.

Screenshot of result:

[image: screenshot]